# How to list all the functions in an Oracle DB and order them by their modification date

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I would like to obtain a list of all functions in an Oracle database, along with their respective modification dates. Is there an SQL query that could provide me with this information?

I attempted to use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'
```

which I found in a Donald Burleson article, but I received an error message stating:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.

Comment: Maybe you don't have the right. If you want to see all functions you have access to, try `all_objects` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're unable to access the `DBA_OBJECTS` view, it is likely due to a lack of necessary privileges granted by the DBA, since this view contains metadata for all objects of the entire database.

However, you can utilize the [`ALL_OBJECTS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_1155.htm) view instead, which contains metadata only for objects that your user has access to. So, if you are able to access this view, you can make use of its `LAST_DDL_TIME` column, which provides the timestamp for the last modification of each object, resulting from a DDL statement (including grants and revokes).

That being said, your query should be updated as follows:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME, LAST_DDL_TIME
FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'
ORDER BY LAST_DDL_TIME DESC
```